# How to define custom WTForms validator class accepting input from custom query factory?

Tags: python, class, factory, flask-wtforms, customvalidator

I am trying to define a custom WTForms validator which I can use to check if a record already exists in the database based on the data combination entered on multiple fields of the same form.

I am stuck and not really sure how to go about this. I am also new to programming and still trying to understand python and honestly some of the stuff [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/) and [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/_modules/wtforms/form/#Form.__init__) are just beyond my current understanding.

so, the models are defined here:

```
class Data1(Base):
__tablename__ = 'data1'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
description = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Data2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Data3(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data3'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    data1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('data1.id'), nullable=False)
    data2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('data2.id'), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

Sample data here:

```
session.add_all([
Data1(id=1, description='a'),
Data1(id=2, description='b'),
Data1(id=3, description='c'),
Data2(id=1, description='aa'),
Data2(id=2, description='bb'),
Data2(id=3, description='cc'),
Data3(id=4, data1_id=1, data2_id=1, description='all first entries of data 1 & 2')
])

session.commit()
```

The problems are defined on my comments below:

```
# Define validator class. This needs to be defined outside the form definition since it will be used in a lot of forms.
class Uniqueness(object):
    def __init__(self, message=None, dbqry=None):
        if not message:
            message = u'Duplicate field combination detected!'
        self.message = message
        self.dbqry = dbqry

    def __call__(self):
        if self.dbqry:
            raise ValidationError(self.message)


# Instantiate validator
uniqueness = Uniqueness


# Define query factory. This needs to be defined outside the form definition since it will be used in a lot of forms.
def qry(dbModel, frm, *atts):
    # Sample target filter to pass on the query at the bottom of this function:
    # fl = [
    #       Data3.data1_id == Myform.data1_id.data
    #       Data3.data2_id == Myform.data2_id.data
    #       Data3.description == Myform.description.data
    #       ]
    # Question1: Referring to the custom validator example [here][3] where 'self' and '.data'
    # attributes were used when validator was defined within form class definition,
    # Is my adaptation sample above suited to the purpose, I am trying to achieve here?
    # If not, then how should I go about this?
    # Question2: How can I generate same list as above which I can pass on to the filter part
    # of the query statement at the bottom of this function?
    # Below is my attempt to answer this:
    fl = []
    for att in atts:
        try:
            hasattr(dbModel, 'att')
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError(f'{dbModel}.{att} is invalid.')
        else:
            mdl_att = str(getattr(dbModel, att))
            # Question3: This is probably wrong since I would then have to use 'eval' at some point right?
            # I don't want to use 'eval' if possible.
        try:
            hasattr(frm, 'att')
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError(f'{frm}.{att} is invalid.')
        else:
            frm_att = str(getattr(frm, att))
            # Question4: If the '.data' attribute from the intended output of the 'fl' example above is indeed required,
            # How would I state it here?
        # Below is suppose to create the list defined above, but I reckon this will create a string 
        # which I can't use.
        # Question6: What is the better way of doing this?
        fl.append(mdl_att + '==' + frm_att)

    # Query the dbModel to check if a record exists with the data combination as defined in fl filter.
    return session.query(dbModel).filter(fl).first()


# Instantiate the query here?
# Question5: 'MyForm' is used before the form class definition, How can this be addressed?
dbQry = qry(Data3, MyForm, 'data1_id', 'data2_id', 'description')


# Define the form
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    # Question5: Or perhaps instantiate inside the form definition?
    # dbQry = qry(Data3, MyForm, 'data1_id', 'data2_id', 'description')
    # if it should be here then how to properly do it?
    choices1 = session.query(Data1.id, Data1.description).all()
    data1_id = SelectField('Select Field 1', choices=choices1, validators=[uniqueness(dbqry=dbQry)])
    choices2 = session.query(Data2.id, Data2.description).all()
    data2_id = SelectField('Select Field 2', choices=choices2, validators=[uniqueness(dbqry=dbQry)])
    description = StringField('Description', validators=[InputRequired(), uniqueness(dbqry=dbQry)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit Data')

# Question5: Or here? 'dbQry' will be used in the above definition before the variable definition below; How can
# this be addressed?
# dbQry = qry(Data3, MyForm, 'data1_id', 'data2_id', 'description')
```

The link I mentioned in the code for the custom validator is [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/). This might not have rendered correctly.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Comment: thanks, I just did that. you might want to help me on the new one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66417197/how-to-unpack-list-of-attributes-to-filter-argument-of-sqlalchemy-orm-query