# How to unpack list of attributes to .filter argument of sqlalchemy orm query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Part of the solution to my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406977/how-to-define-custom-wtforms-validator-class-accepting-input-from-custom-query-f).

For the query factory I managed to come up with a list for the filter like so:

```
fl = [{'Data3.data1_id': 'MyForm.data1_id'}, {'Data3.data2_id': 'MyForm.data2_id'}, {'Data3.description': 'MyForm.description'}]
```

I want to pass this to the query below:

```py
q = session.query(dbModel).filter(*[(getattr(k) == getattr(v) for k, v in item) for item in fl]
        ).first()
```

The above code doesn't work and I am getting the following error:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'generator'> instead
```

How can I change my code so the `fl` list will be unpacked in a similar manner as below. Or is there a better way of doing this?

```
q = session.query(dbModel).filter(
        Data3.data1_id == MyForm.data1_id, Data3.data2_id == MyForm.data2_id, Data3.description == MyForm.description
    ).first()
```

Finally when the query is run, the MyForm attribute values will be retrieved like so:

```
q = session.query(dbModel).filter(
        Data3.data1_id == 1, Data3.data2_id == 1, Data3.description == 'all first entries of data 1 & 2'
    ).first()
```

Note that the values in the preceding codes are the values assigned to the 'MyForm.attributes' on the second line.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: thanks @rfkortekaas. I have changed the code and I think it is iterating through each kv for each item in the fl now. But then SQLAlchemy throws an error this time 'sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'generator'> instead'. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have accidentally closed this question when I clicked on the suggested solution. How can it be reopened?